# PHP File Based Caching vs reading direct from DB like MySQL or MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, caching, io

I am a student of Computing, I work as a web developer using PHP. I have worked on a web application which has a lot of SQL queries that might be sent to the database server +-20 times to query the same information per page load.

For this reason. I decided to go with my own custom File Based Caching by extending the codeIgiter caching library which is unusable due to its reliance on the URL/URI. I basically took out the URL/URI dependency and used SHA-256 for access keys. I store all my cached data as encrypted data using the default CodeIgniter encryption library just to add extra security in case someone opens the cache file, I did not  want to store plain text data.

- Is the encryption for the cached data expensive/resource heavy on server?
- Is file based caching faster than the Mysql/MariaDB/PostGres?

File Based Caching works great for me to minimise database queries, but can this really improve the speed on my web application? How fast is can this be, versus DB?

I got carried away with excitement, as a result my web application is now a farm of cache is this good or bad for speed? I need advise from people with more experience on this topic.

My Custom File Based caching has these basic functions:

- save($key,$value)
- get($key)
- delete($key) or delete($key,$value)
- metadata($key)

Thank you.

Comment: There's no proper way to answer this without a LOT more details than you're providing. The only possible answer is "go benchmark your stuff using DBs and your own cache, and see what's faster"

Comment: Please ask me what you would like me to explain, I tried to be clear, but obviously I have failed :)

Comment: -- you pointed out something important. I will test this using CI built in benchmarking, please share if you know of a better tool.

Comment: What about using [MySQL with memcached](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ha-memcached.html)?

Comment: I have tried using memcached. very unhappy with the result. I am not convinced at all. No improvement on slowness at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use memcached or redish for the caching which will reduce the number of queries on the database and it will improve the speed of the site.

Apart from the that check the queries and optimize them.

Comment: please see my response to VMai, do you think I need to experiment with memcached a bit more? I installed memcached on Sles box which we use for production at work. Very unhappy with it. If queries are not optimized can that also lead to a slow memcache? (Don’t think so though, but I am less experienced). I have no experience with redish (Never tried it)

Comment: I just looked at http://redis.io/ , my initial impression is that this is very similar to my custom file based caching except that I am just keeping encryted. I also use key-value cache and key is a sha-256 hash, but I am still trying to dive into the documentation, but thanks for sharing, I had no idea http://redis.io/ existed before your comment. #ThumbsUp

Basically with my custom solution, the only worry is the file io speed.

Comment: Wow this looks great - https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis#usage

I feel like my brain just opened up to whole new learning area, this is exciting but I feel like this will slow me down with my project. I want to launch soon :(